# Is code formatting working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I posted [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-is-the-correct-way-to-work-with-custom-data-in-the-api/118#118), but code formatting hasn't worked. Since it's simply (?) a matter of indenting code by four spaces and a blank line before and after, I suspect this shouldn't be a browser issue.

Is code formatting working on civicrm.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work:

- Bullet
- Bullet followed by blank line

  ```
  Here is some code which I indented 8 spaces.
  ```
- Bullet preceded by blank line.

Comment: Hmm ... I had blank lines also but nvm, all good now

Comment: I think the key is that code is normally indented 4 lines, but code in a bulleted list is indented 8 lines.

Comment: Right, double indent or clear the block with a "normal" para.

Answer (score 1):

If you want code inside a list you need to indent 8 spaces, 4 for the list and 4 for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Yes, it is working, but a single blank line doesn't clear a list block apparently.

This doesn't work:

- list item
- list item (followed by blank line)

  code sample (indented four spaces)

This does work:

- list item
- list item (followed by blank line)

Regular text with no space prefix.

```
code sample (indented four spaces).
```

So, the solution was to insert a line of text (= normal block) between the list and the code sample.